# Vim syntax highlighting for multiline fortran openmp directives

Tags: vim, openmp, fortran90, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using modern fortran for doing parallel programming. I'm using vim and it's been really annoying me that the fortran.vim syntax files don't seem to handle compiler directives like !$omp or !dir$. These just get rendered as comments in vim so they don't stand out. In c/c++ these compiler directives are done using #pragma's so everything stands out like it were preprocessor code rather than comment code. So I want similar treatment in my fortran syntax.
Here's an example of a multiline directive that I want to colour:

```
!$omp parallel do reduction(+: sum0) reduction(+: sum1) &
     private( nn, S1, S2, Y1, Y2, rvec0, rvec1, iThreadNum)
```

What I have so far is a new fortran.vim file located in $HOME/.vim/after/syntax.
I've got it to recognise the '!$omp' at the start of a line and to colour that line and also to colour the multilines properly. My syntax file contains this:

```
syn region fortranDirective start=/!$omp.*/ end=/[^\&]$/
hi def link fortranDirective PreProc
```

My problem is that it now can't handle the simple case of just a single line. I.e:

```
!$omp parallel do blah blah
call foobar   <-- this is coloured the same as the line above
```

I need some kind of regex rule in my syntax file to be able to correctly match both single line and continued line. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem is that your start regex is too greedy.

This should work:

```
syn region fortranDirective start=/!$omp.\{-}/ end=/[^\&]$/
```

Comment: Ah simple! That seems to have fixed it.Thanks!