# Vim syntax highlighting for Fortran OpenMP comments

Tags: vim, fortran, openmp, fortran90, vim-syntax-highlighting

There was a very useful answer on how to highlight openmp directives in Fortran code ([Vim syntax highlighting for multiline fortran openmp directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026223)).
So lines like

```
!$omp parallel
```

are no longer highlighted as comments.

It would be great also to make vim not to treat as comments
lines starting with "`!$`", i.e. in constructs like

```
! Make it compile both with and without OMP
nThreads = 1
!$ nThreads = omp_get_num_threads()
```

I want to  have `!$` highlighted as `fortrandirective`,
and the rest of the last line highlighted normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `syn match` for this:

```
:syn match fortranDirective "\v!\$\s"
```

This matches `!$` with a trailing whitespace (to distinguish it from `!$omp`).